# Create Panels like newer twitter Bootstrap version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2.

I like the new [panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) which are provided in Twitter Bootstrap 3RC2 and would like to use them.

How can I get the CSS for Panels only from new version?

Comment: You didn't say what bootstrap version are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the panel section from the new [css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3.0.0-wip/dist/css/bootstrap.css) and everything should be fine.
You might have to customize it a little bit.

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/j4CKA/).

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel content
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @nikhilsugandh: I don't quite understand your question. Cheers.